# JQM refresh collapsible set doesnt refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I need help with a little script ...

when i append content and drigger create tho content is loaded...

but then when i use `$('#set').empty();` for the second time the content is loaded but no JQM style is added (just plain text)

i have read about this problem but i dont find any solution ... i guess that `$('#set').collapsibleset('refresh');`as it should... any idea ?

thanks

```
var content ="<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + i + "'><h3>Sectionit " + i + "</h3><p>I\'m collapsible number ' + i + '</p></div>";

             $('#set').append(content).trigger("create");
             $('#set').collapsibleset('refresh');
```

Comment: `.collapsibleset();` without refresh.

Comment: it desnt work.... it doesn't even pass the line of code (tried with alert)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var content ="<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + i + "'><h3>Sectionit " + i + "</h3><p>I\'m collapsible number ' + i + '</p></div>";

$('#set').append(content).trigger("create");
$('#set').collapsibleset('refresh');
```

try

```
$('#set').empty();
var content ="<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + i + "'><h3>Sectionit " + i + "</h3><p>I\'m collapsible number ' + i + '</p></div>";

$('#set').append(content);
$('#set').collapsibleset().trigger("create");
```

In this way you only call trigger('create') once after all content has been added.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/2/)**

Comment: the code stops at $('#set').collapsibleset().trigger("create");  i tested with alerts

Comment: @LitBe, see demo i added to answer( http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/1/ ). click the recreate button and see it work.

Comment: are you sure ? when i click recreate  the list is gone?

Comment: @LitBe, sorry, made a bad edit, try this updated link:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/2/

Comment: ok i saw your code ... but i dont think it is what i need ...  I just need the collapsible that was created to be "recreated" (emptyed and created again with my code)... the problem is ... when is recreated it looses the stlye....

Comment: Are you confusing Collapsibles and CollapsibleSets? Try var content =$("<div data-role='collapsible' id='set" + i + "'><h3>Sectionit " + i + "</h3><p>I\'m collapsible number ' + i + '</p></div>"); $('#set').append(content); content.collapsible();

Comment: I have <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d" id="set" class="set"></div> in the content ....  is there a problem that i have a multipage layout ?  becouse content.collapsible();  doesnt work ...

Comment: @LitBe, Can you just update my jsFiddle to reproduce your issue?

Comment: the problem is that i work with JQM 1.4 thats not supported on jsfiddle... but I will try to put a sample on so you cant at least see the code

Comment: @LitBe, my fiddle is using 1.4 via external resources

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f3G3U/

As I said it doesnt work ... probably couse JQM 1.4 ... at least you will see the code...

When I let's say click on Prostor1 it goes to #pagetest and show all the content with style and everything... then I go back ... I click or Prostor1,2,3 ... and on #pagetest the content is ok but the style is missing ...  do you understand the problem ?

Comment: @LitBe, this seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/6/.  content.collapsible(); within the loop and $('#set').collapsibleset(); after the loop.

Comment: i was happy as hell for a momment ... but it doesnt work on firefox :S

Comment: content.collapsible();  and  $('#set').collapsibleset(); couse problems ... as I asked ... is there maybe a problem couse the multipage layout ?

Comment: @LitBe, for me it works fine in Firefox v26. I have re-written the fiddle to use jQM events and navigation, give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/7/

Comment: first I must thank you for all your help... very kind of you ...  i replaced all the code... but still ... it doesnt work... 

if it helps... I use JQM 1.4 and JQ 2.0.3 ... with phonegap...

Comment: @LitBe, see if using jQ 1.10.1 makes a difference.

Comment: yes it makes a difference ... it doesnt work at all ...  all pages apper and no style ... the same if I use JQ 2.0.3 on your JSFiddle ... check it

http://jsfiddle.net/8z5Rz/8/

Comment: @LitBe, 2.0.3 works fine on my fiddle, you just had the files in the wrong order (jQ must be before jQM js): http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/9/

Comment: @LitBe, One last try: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/10/ Moved the collapsible() and collapsibleset() into the pagebeforeshow of the second page...

Comment: do you mind if i send you tomorow my whole code so you can check ... ?  Couse something must be reall wrong ... ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @ezanker .... the problem was that i had this in the document <head>

<code><script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/mediaelementplayer.css" /></code>

so it seems i had two jQuery files ... thanks for all your help :) I accepted your answer couse the code works !